# Is "avenging the deaths of other players" bugged?

Tags: assassins-creed-valhalla

There's a Ubisoft Connect mission to "avenge the deaths of 10 other players". I've completed the game's story and haven't encountered a single other player to avenge, even though I've been playing while connected to the internet, and can see other players' in-game photos on the world map. My PS+ subscription is also current (I have the PS5 version of the game). Is this feature currently broken, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a bug fixed after version 1.3.0 (probably [1.3.2](https://www.ubisoft.com/en-gb/game/assassins-creed/valhalla/news-updates/1xpuIUJm06avDf4hqBkBUG/assassins-creed-valhalla-title-update-132)).

If it is still not showing up - Go to Options->Interface and turn on Celebrations.